# 'return object[value1][value2] || default' fails if value1 is not a valid property

Tags: typescript, object-literal

I have an object literal with a method to return a sub-property given a particular input, or return a default property if the lookup fails.

```js
//private class, no export
class TemplateSelection {
  'bills';
  'legislators';
}

export class ComponentTemplates {
  private readonly 'notFound';
  private readonly 'data': {
    'us': TemplateSelection,
    'ny': TemplateSelection,
  }

  constructor(){
    this.notFound = PageNotFoundComponent;

    this.data = {
      us: { bills: BillDataComponent, legislators: UsComponent },
      ny: { bills: BillDataComponent, legislators: NyComponent },
    }
  }

  public getData = (requested: RouteParameters) => {
    // TODO: lookup fails if !requested.region, but not if !requested.resourceType?
    return this.data[requested.region][requested.resourceType] || this.notFound;
  }
}
```

1. If `[requested.region] == 'us'` & `[requested.resourceType] == 'bills'`, I get the `BillDataComponent` component, as expected.
2. If `[requested.region] == 'ny'` and `[requested.resourceType] == 'monkeys'`, I get the PageNotFoundComponent, as expected.
3. If `[requested.region] == 'monkeys'` and `[requested.resourceType] == 'legislators'`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'legislators' of undefined` in my project.

It appears that the `||` comparison is only looking at the last lookup key rather than both, but it doesn't appear that any combination of brackets, braces, or parentheses seems to extend that comparison to the whole of `this.data[requested.region][requested.resourceType]`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Javascript doesn't currently natively support [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), you have to check the intermediate values or use some other alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any other newbs out there, as @Nit [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719439/return-objectvalue1value2-default-fails-if-value1-is-not-a-valid-proper#comment101880534_57719439), JavaScript doesn't currently support so-called "[Optional Chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)"; the (sadly quite ugly) "solution" was to side step the issue with an `if/else` check on the first parameter, like so:

```
  public getData = (requested: RouteParameters) => {
    if (this.regions.includes(requested.region))
      return this.components[requested.region][requested.resourceType] || this.notFound;
    else return this.notFound;
  }
```